# Rename a table in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, ddl, quoted-identifier

I've been trying to rename a table from "fund performance" to fund_performance in SQLWorkbench for a Redshift database. Commands I have tried are:

```
alter table schemaname."fund performance"
rename to fund_performance;
```

I received a message that the command executed successfully, and yet the table name did not change.
I then tried copying the table to rename it that way. I used

```
#CREATE TABLE fund_performance LIKE "schema_name.fund performance";
CREATE TABLE fund_performance AS SELECT * FROM schema_name."fund performance";
```

In both these cases I also received a message that the statements executed successfully, but nothing changed. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: check in other default schemas in there it may be got created

Comment: It could be that SQLWorkbench is caching the name of the table. After you use the `ALTER TABLE` command, are you able to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fund_performance`? Also, check whether SQLWorkbench has Auto-Commit enabled (turn it on). This shouldn't impact DDL statements, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Use following it may work out for you

```
SELECT * into schema_name.fund_performance FROM schema_name.[fund performance]
```

It will copy the data by creating new table as **fund_performance** but it won't create any constraints and Identity's

To Rename specific table without disturbing existing constraints

```
EXEC sp_rename 'schema_name.[fund performance]', 'schema_name.fund_performance';
```

Comment: which works on MSSQL